Finding area of triangle in Argand Plane

Given $|z|^2=4$, find the area of the triangle formed by the complex numbers $z$, $\omega z$, $z+\omega z$ (here, $\omega$ is the complex cube root of unity).

I understand the solution which claims that the given numbers form an equilateral triangle and then finds the area.
My doubt is, as $z$ only needs to satisfy $|z|=2$ so I assume a complex number $z=2i$, go on to find $\omega z$ and $z+\omega z$, I am not getting an equilateral triangle in this case. What's the mistake i am making in assuming $z=2i$?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

It seems like your doubts are justified. Can't you just take the solution and substitute for $z$ and $w$ the values from your counterexample, and see where it starts to go wrong?

The numbers $z$, $\omega z$, and $-(z+\omega z)$ form an equilateral triangle. It looks like either you dropped a minus sign, or whoever set the question did.

From what i understand though the points don't form an equilateral triangle but the vectors along these three points do form an equilateral triangle, the answer by taking z, wz and z+wz as points matches with the area of an equilateral triangle formed by z, wz and z+wz as directed vectors

thanks for responding guys
